# ¿Como puedo exportar un excel predeterminado con una consulta en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

Estoy intentando exportar un archivo con una consulta `DB::raw()` en Laravel 5.8 pero al intentar ejecutar la consulta me retornar un error. Anexo la información de mi controlador, Clase de exportación y el error que se presenta:

```
 public function exportar(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        "reporte" => "required"
    ]);

    Excel::download(new ReportesExport,"reporte_export.xlsx");
}
```

Clase:

```
use App\Reporte;
use App\Pedido;
use App\Producto;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ReportesExport implements FromCollection
{

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
      return DB::select("SELECT p.numero_pedido,p.valor_pedido,p.fecha,p.cliente,(SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(pro.nombre) from productos pro where pedido_id=p.id) productos,(SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(cli.nombre) from clientes cli where cli.reporte_id=r.id group by reporte_id) clientes FROM reportes r INNER JOIN pedidos p ON p.reporte_id=r.id where r.id=? GROUP BY p.id", [Reporte::getUltimoReporte()->id]);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"message": "Call to a member function all() on array",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\casa\\Papa\\vendor\\maatwebsite\\excel\\src\\Sheet.php",
    "line": 400,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo su nombre lo dice, el método `collection` espera que tipo retornado sea una `collection` *([ref](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html))*, actualmente su consulta retornará un `array`.

La solución más rápida es instancia el array a una collection, usando el helper [collect](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-collect) de Laravel o revisar la opción [FromQuery](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html) del paquete.

```
public function collection()
{
  return collect(DB::select("....",[]));
}
```